# Is the inversion in the mentioned context idiomatic/grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, inversion, idiomatic-language, subject-auxiliary-inversion

> But, in either of the above ways **is** intentionality defined, why not to
>   use the previously mentioned criteria to identify an intentional
>   crime?

In the above sentence "is" is put before the subject. Is this inversion idiomatic/grammatical?

Comment: Source of the sentence?

Comment: @CinCout My own work!

Comment: related: [Question-like structure (word order) in non-question sentences](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53609/question-like-structure-word-order-in-non-question-sentences) **and** [Structure: Very Few Times](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24151/structure-very-few-times/24155#24155)

Answer (score 1):

The example needs more context in order to fully understand what the message is. I don't really understand the OP's sentence.

Inversion is used with **negative adverbials** and **expressions** in positive sentences. The position of subject and the auxiliary verb is inverted (switched=swapped). For example,

1. ***Not only*** *does she* speak three languages fluently, (but) she writes children's books too.
2. ***No sooner*** *had she* posted her question **than** someone jumped on her back.
3. She posted her answer. **Only then** *was she* able to relax
4. ***Never*** *was* so much owed by *so many* to so few (Winston Churchill)
5. **Hardly** *had I* finished writing my answer **when** it got downvoted :)

Inversion is useful for adding emphasis, and in (very) formal *writing*.